# How to correctly traverse a 2D Array?

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
matrix = [[0 for x in range(26)] for y in range(26)]
for i in range(26):
    for j in range(26):
        matrix[i][j] = ...
```

This code actually works, but the 'j' in 'matrix[i][j]' always gives me a warning:

```
Unexpected type(s): (int, float) Possible types: (int, int) (slice, Iterable[int]) less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info: This inspection detects type errors in function call expressions. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Types of function parameters can be specified in docstrings or in Python 3 function annotations.
```

Can someone please advise why this can happen and how to fix it? Thanks.

BTW, I use PyCharm Community 2018.2.

Comment: Are you sure the warning isn't triggered by the code in the `...`?

Comment: Pretty sure, even if I assign '1' to it there is still this warning.